# REST API and React Frontend - CORS

Tags: rest, laravel, reactjs, cors

Im setting up a Laravel API which interacts with several frontends, one of which is a React frontend.  However, Im running CORS issues no matter what I do.

I'd like the API and the React front to have their own sub domains:

api.mysite.com
webview.mysite.com

How is this generally accomplished?  Do you just need to set all the CORS directives, or is there a preferred approach to handling separate frontends and APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just have to setup CORS. I usually do this up using the [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package which makes it very easy to setup.

Comment: This worked to some degree, but some requests were still failing even with the package.  It's unclear because the github docs seem different than the packagist ones.  By default, does the package make everything wide open?  Because if I can't make it work there, I can't make it work with more config options probably...

Comment: How are you handling your authentication? Using a session or an auth token?

Comment: How are you using the middleware? On a route group like this: `Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors']....` or as a global middleware for all routes?

Comment: im using `cors` middleware in a route group, which covers all the routes

Comment: Try using the global one just to see if it works. I found this issue which might be related: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/110

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I sitll get issues.  Specifically "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api-staging.mysite.com/resources/me/favoriteStation. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://the-request-site.com"